# Is there a way to use a 'react-icon' with React Native?

Tags: javascript, css, react-native, react-icons

Im actually writing a code in React native but while using react-icon I still don't know how to import an icon on my project.
I've tried with components such as Image but I don't see them on my Screen.

Please help me, below I share the code:

```
import { StyleSheet,Image, View, } from 'react-native';
import { AiOutlineHome } from 'react-icons/ai';

export function Navbar() {
  return (
    <View style={style.nav}>
        <Image
        style={style.navIcon}
        source={<AiOutlineHome/>}
        />
    </View>
  )
}

const style = StyleSheet.create({
    nav:{
        width:'100%',
        height:50,

        position:'absolute',
        top:702,
    },
    navIcon:{
        color:'red',
        resize:'cover'
    }
})
```

Comment: have you tried adding the element directly to the view instead of trying to wrap it inside another element?  i.e. `<View style={style.nav}><AiOutlineHome /></View>`?

Comment: Yes, and it gives me an error: 'view config getter callback for the component `path` must be a function'

Answer (score 2):

`react-icons` is not designed to be used with React Native.

Try this library - https://github.com/oblador/react-native-vector-icons